# TextInput Width - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a TextInput in my React Native App. All this while I was using simulator "iPhone X" and it was working fine. Now I changed my simulator to "iPhone 5" and the width doesn't match.

```
                  <TextInput  
                    value={value} 
                    placeholder='Search Here...'
                    onChangeText={(text)=>{this.handleSearch(text)}
                    onTouchStart={()=>{this.setTempNotifications()}
                    style={{ height: 40, width: 290}}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    selectTextOnFocus={true}
                  />
```

I had set the width to "290". How do I make my TextInput width flexible???? It has to fit all phone screens and I do not have to fix a width.

Comment: what do you mean by flexible do you want to occupy all the available width ?

Comment: What I meant is I set "width: 290". This is only applicable for iPhone X. How do I set the width of my TextInput so that it fits all phone screens. Does this work "width: 100%" ??

Comment: try with a percentage something like width:'80%'

Comment: when you set to Width: '100%'.  It takes  100% of the width size declared. which makes it work for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to give a width value. Only the height is enough to make the TextInput span across its parent.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput  
          placeholder='Search Here...'                  
          style={{ height: 40, borderWidth: 1}}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          selectTextOnFocus={true}
          />
    </View>
  );
}
```

The containing view can have `padding` or `margin` for appropriate gutter space